# How to share PDF, XIS, DOC, PNG from URL

Tags: java, android

Here is my code

```
Glide.with(getContext())
                    .asBitmap().skipMemoryCache(true).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .load(url)
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(250, 250) {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Share");
                            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContext().getContentResolver(), resource, "", null);
                            Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
                            intent.setType("*/*");
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send to"));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            super.onLoadFailed(errorDrawable);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadStarted(Drawable placeholder) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sharing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            super.onLoadStarted(placeholder);
                        }
                    });
```

I am implementing share option in my Android application using URL. The URL contains all types of files like PDF, PNG, DOC, DOCX, etc. I tried to share PNG file among other apps and it's working fine.

The issue is I cannot able to share PDF and other format files except image. How can I share all the MIME type files?

Comment: This can help you, `public static String getMimeType(File file)`
 https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java

Comment: MIME TYPE i got from server the issue is i want to share all kind of files like pdf,doc,docx

Answer (score 0):

May this example help you, I used this code for Sending PDF files, you can send mutiple by using array and Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE:

```
public void shareFile(File file) {
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, com.example.app, file);
        shareFile(uri);
    }
```

Call shareFile function and pass URI

```
private void shareFile(Uri uri) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mContext.getString(R.string.file_with_message));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select app to send file");
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response i want to share all kind of files not only a pdf